# ReactJS "Книга перемен" Создание функциональности

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Прошу не судить меня строго :/ Я недавно начал изучать React, а вместе с ним и JavaScript. Мне нужно реализовать функционал, "Книга перемен", как на сайте (https://cha.com.ua/ru/kniga-peremen-i-czin/). Возможно вы можете что-то посоветовать, с чего начать и в каком направлении двигаться? Возможно уже есть ответ особо не искал, убедительная просьба ткнуть носом!) Заранее всем спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]